# Visual Studio - File changes not saved to original disk location?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Ok, complete Visual Studio & Windows development noob here - there's gotta be an easy answer to this.

I've just started working on porting a Linux C++ library to Windows.  Existing source tree is on the Linux file system, VS is running in a Windows 7 VM, which has the Linux file system mounted.

I added the source tree to a new project - I was initially doing the edits on the linux side, but now I've done a few from the VS IDE.  But those edits aren't showing up on the disk??  I've done the typical save: ctrl-s, done the "save all": ctrl-shift-s, saved from the menu, etc.  If I look at the file on the disk on the linux side, the changes aren't there.

I've shut down & restarted VS, and it still sees the changes on restart.  How do I get the changes back on the actual disk so I can commit to subversion, etc.?

I've confirmed that the files & file system are read/writable from the Windows VM.

I'm sure this made sense to somebody, but I'll be damned if I get it.

Visual Studio Professional 2013 on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be reading/writing to the same directory under both environments, imo. Not the least reasons of which is that *nix & windows have different ideas of line endings.

It would be much better to keep a git repository on your host OS (or on a server like github) and pull/push to that repo from your windows VM. Git is smart enough to handle all the line endings, symbolic links, permissions, etc. automagically.

Comment: Fair enough - doing it mostly because the VM file system has pretty limited space, and the corporate revision control system is Subversion, which I'm very familiar with on Linux.  I'm trying to do bite sized chunks here, and bridging GIT to Subversion within Visual Studio seems like a stretch when I can't even get my changes to show up on the disk!  Not worried about the line endings - dos2unix/unix2dos are my friends.

Comment: I should've been less specific in my answer; subversion fills the same role as Git in my suggestion. If you have both your linux machine & windows machine pulling from a subversion server (or if the linux machine acts as a svn server for your windows box) then you will likely have a much easier time managing the differences.

Comment: Ok - thought you were referring to the revision control integrated into VS, which appears to be only GIT.

I guess the other thing I've been doing is trying to check the changes required to make sure everything still works on the Linux side before I commit, which is another reason why I kept the source tree on the Linux side - so I can build and run the test infrastructure against it there.

Guess I'll have to fork things and use svn to move things around.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar behavior using BC++ IDE.
In my case I was trying to edit files that were hard links to files in a second directory (on the same NTFS file system).
The IDE is using some mechanism to reposition the file to be edited into the _history backup directory.

I.e. the editor unlinks the original file in the original directory and relinks it in the _history subdirectory and creates a completely new directory entry for the edited file.
The hard linked file  I created in the second directory is thus then linked to the backup file in the _history directory so when I edit the file in the second directory with notepad, the modifications appear in the _history backup file (or vica versa) but not the file in the originial location.

Its not like a simple text editor (notepad) where the edited file is opened-read-closed  and when saved, reopen-written-closed using the same directory entry.
I presume that the IDE is using a low level Windows file system function to rename/link the original file into the _history 
directory and that this mechanism does not support/recognize NTFS hard links. I suspect in your case that VS may use a similar relinking mechanism (specific to NTFS) that similarly would not work with the files in the mounted Linux file system.
That VS may be storing edits in a temporary file (may be hidden or in some other temporary directory) so the original file is not lost if the IDE crashes. When the file save is committed it attempts to link the original file to backup and then attempts to relink the temporary edit file into the original directory entry location, but because the NTFS file system linking mechanism is not compatible  with the Linux file system, nothing happens.
[I do observe temporary files appear like this when editing MicroSoft Office documents. notepad++ also does this, so I suspect VS is doing the same thing.]

Comment: Wow - so you're basically saying that Visual Studio won't work correctly unless everything is hosted on a Windows based file system?  Is there any way to change this behavior?  That's pretty amazing to me that something as simple and basic as saving a file won't work unless you're operating in a monoculture.

Comment: BC++ builder has an option to disable the history, but this did solve the problem for me as I suspect it still uses the relocation mechanism for the temporary file. I ended up using SVN which (unlike GIT) let me "cherrypick" so I could checkout just the files/subdirectories I wanted from my repositories.